# How can i design Islamic Prayer Time Widget for specific city or country?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I need to design an Islamic Prayer Time Widget using ASP.Net, C#. I have no idea about this. Can any one tell me if I can consume such service from other website so that I can add custom design to it or how I can design this for website.

I would appreciate if some one can point me in the right direction.

**Other Solution:** added on 18/03/2012

I have also found good example on how to create Islamic Prayer Time widget in different language and calculation that are also required for such widget.  It is worth checking out

http://praytimes.org/manual/

Above site has code example in different languages also such as C#, C++, PHP, Python and Objective C also.

Comment: Not sure what your specific question is? Which aspect of doing it are you asking about - getting the location, getting prayer times, building a widget?

Comment: Should the widget be used in your own website or in diffrent website?

Comment: By finding out when different types of Muslims like to pray in the different parts of the world. I imagine there several factors at play here, other than doctrine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this helps, I would highly recommend that you should think about an Object-oriented concept before designing. There are existing widgets already and I reckon you are writing yours from scratch.

helpful link for idea [here](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=493627).

3 things:

1. Map for sun movement.
2. [Formula](http://www.tanzil.info/praytime/doc/calculation/) for prayer time
3. Design proper OO code and think your design through.

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I've worked on Islamic Prayer Times before. This link has access to a widget in which you can enter your location, and the widget will display prayer times for that area:

http://www.masykur.web.id/post/prayer-time-widget-for-blogengine-net-1-4-x.aspx

---

If you are actually after data for the prayer times so you can build your own widget, the widget above uses the following:

http://www.islamway.com/flashes/7/PrayerTimes.zip